# c++ max & min without if or else

Tags: c++

I want a way to `cout <<` maximum & minimum of two numbers with `cin >>` without `if()` or `else()`. I tried before and I just found the if and else way. I want the way even without `?`.

Comment: What are the types? What's you objection to `std::min` and `std::max`?

Comment: You can use `std::max` and `std::min`.

Comment: Just float or int.

Comment: How can I use them in code?

Comment: So `std::max<float>` or `std::min<int>` ? They're templates.

Comment: If it is a homework and you need your own solution, you can try for example `vmax = (a+b + std::abs(a-b))/2`.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

...
auto s = std::minmax(10, 2);
std::cout << s.first << ", " << s.second << "\n";
```

Do resist the temptation to write a macro or so.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be interested in [branchless programming](https://cppcon.digital-medium.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/Branchless_computing.pdf) (this isn't really the best link, but it'll hopefully be enough to get started if you've never heard of this - I couldn't find anything better with a quick google).

Here's a way to do it with no conditional jumps - nor using any functions that wrap the conditional jumps:

```
// given two numbers, x and y
int min = (x < y)*x + (y <= x)*y;
int max = (x > y)*x + (y >= x)*y;
```

[demo](https://godbolt.org/z/oKaj9b7M7)

This works because the comparison operators return `0` if false, and `1` if true. This is basically the whole idea of branchless programming.

As much as this is fun, it's not very readable and may actually hinder performance in places like this - and a compiler will often do this kind of thing for you behind the scenes if it deems it worth it.

Comment: Are you sure `(x < y)` is branchless?

Comment: @Bathsheba , yes. Technically it's still c++ code, and the compiler can do as it pleases so long as it maintains the logic (which means it could add branching). But in practice, yes. When you learn the basics of assembly you'll find that this is a comparison which doesn't change the instruction pointer (other than the normal increment).

Comment: It is branchless, but not comparisonless. The OP only said, if/else/? is not accepted. So the question is, how literal to interpret that requirement.

Comment: I would take that source with several grains of salt. For instance, it assumes `bool temp = x || y` is a branch due to short-circuiting. That's allowed but modern compilers can generally spot a lack of side-effects and remove the branch.

Comment: @MSalters, fair point. I was surprised to spend two minutes googling and not find a great source. It was just a starting place for readers, but I'll add a comment beside it.

Comment: @Elliott The point is that it is a good answer, but we all do not know, what the OP actually wants

Comment: @Sebastian, ah yes. I see what you mean now.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple way with abs, but make sure the values do not overflow (not int overflow safe)**

```
int max = (abs(a-b)+a+b)/2;
int min = (-abs(a-b)+a+b)/2;
```

Because `a+b = min+max`

and

`abs(a-b) = max-min`

Overflowing of signed ints leads to undefined behavior; if you cast to unsigned ints before the arithmetic operations and back to signed ints for the `abs` instead you just get a wrong result, when the numbers overflow. Simple checking would need conditionals.

**Alternative way with 64-bit operations (int overflow safe)**

If `int` is shorter than 64-bit, then this would work:

```
unsigned long long int ulla = static_cast<unsigned long long int>(a);
unsigned long long int ullb = static_cast<unsigned long long int>(b);
int max = static_cast<int>((abs(ulla-ullb)+ulla+ullb)/2);
int min = static_cast<int>((-abs(ulla-ullb)+ulla+ullb)/2);
```

**Alternative way with boolean operations (int overflow safe)**

(implemented for 32-bit ints, needs C++20 for guaranteed two's complement of signed numbers)

```
unsigned int ua = static_cast<unsigned int>(a);
unsigned int ub = static_cast<unsigned int>(b);
unsigned int uha = static_cast<unsigned int>(a/2);
unsigned int uhb = static_cast<unsigned int>(b/2);
// (b/2 larger) or (equal and (b larger))
unsigned int maskmsb = ((uha-uhb) ¦ ((uha - uhb) ^ (uha - uhb - 1)) & (ua - ub)) >> 31;
unsigned int mask2 = maskmsb - 1;
unsigned int mask1 = ~mask2;

max = static_cast<int>((ub & mask1) ¦ (ua & mask2));
min = static_cast<int>((ub & mask2) ¦ (ua & mask1));
```

Boolean operations should be normally only done on unsigned types, so we cast. Casting back and forth between signed and unsigned numbers should keep the value for any signed number.

The complicated mask calculation is for generating 'the 33th bit' when comparing.
Alternatively we could use 64 bit calculations, then the mask is just `maskmsb = (ulla-ullb) >> 63`.

```
unsigned long long int ulla = static_cast<unsigned long long int>(a);
unsigned long long int ullb = static_cast<unsigned long long int>(b);
unsigned int maskmsb = (ulla - ullb) >> 63;
unsigned long long int mask2 = maskmsb - 1;
unsigned long long int mask1 = ~mask2;

max = static_cast<int>((ullb & mask1) ¦ (ulla & mask2));
min = static_cast<int>((ullb & mask2) ¦ (ulla & mask1));
```

As all the casting between signed and unsigned integer of same bit width is just interpretation of the number, the code looks a lot longer than what it ends up as in assembly. (But it is still suboptimal, because CPUs have flag registers just for this.

Comment: Although flashy, this is vulnerable to `int` overflow. It's always better to use the C++ standard library functions.

Comment: @Bathsheba As the allowed means were limited by the OP not to use conditionals, I do not think that ready-to-use standard library functions would be acceptable either.

Comment: It also totally hides the intent.

Comment: int overflow could be prevented in a way without conditionals by calculating the upper and lower bits separately (e.g. `abs(a/2-b/2)`), but it gets quite complicated. The alternative would be boolean bit operations by extracting masks out of which number is larger.

Comment: @xtofl Either hiding the intent is the intent or it could be abstracted into a function.

Comment: @Sebastian: That's life I'm afraid. If you can't use the `std` functions then it gets complicated. It would be worth making the changes in the answer.